# how to solve infinite geometric

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A rubber ball is dropped from a height of $96$ meters and on each bounce it rebounds up $22%$ of it's previous height, how far has the ball traveled when it hits the ground for the 13th time?

Comment: This is not infinite geometric then, because the question is asking for the distance it travelled when it hits the ground for the $13$th time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Anyway the answer is just $96 + 2(0.22\times96) + 2(0.22^2\times96)+\dots+2(0.22^{12}\times96) = \{96 + (0.22\times96) + (0.22^2\times96)+\dots+(0.22^{12}\times96)\}+ \{(0.22\times96) + (0.22^2\times96)+\dots+(0.22^{12}\times96)\}$

which is just 2 finite geometric series